# How can I tell whether a Magento user is an administrator?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento 1.5, and I need to check whether the currently-logged-in user is an admin user. I need to check this from the user end, because I need to do a process for members that depends on whether they're admin users or not.

Is this possible in Magento?

Comment: More details would help, the question is semi-vague.

Comment: Sometimes it will be impossible because of cookie security. If the admin and store are on different domains, or (more likely) the admin is secured and the frontend is not, the admin session could be inaccessible from the frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin();
```

Comment: or use Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$admin = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getAdmin();
if($admin->getId() != '') {//Admin is logged in}
```

Comment: Use **$admin = Mage::getModel('admin/session')->getAdmin();** to get admin details. Your code gives only user details

Comment: it gives user details of logged in admin user... so you know if anyone is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getUser();
```