# Check if Admin is Logged in Within Observer

Tags: magento

I'm attempting to check if the administrator is logged in from an observer. The problem is that while this is easy to do when viewing the admin module, viewing the frontend is another story.

There are several [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626208/get-admin-session-from-user-end), but unfortunately none of them provide a working solution for Magento 1.6.2.

I wasn't able to successfully get `isLoggedIn()` to return true in the `admin/session` class. I also found out that there is a cookie for both frontend and adminhtml, which may help.

The accepted answer in this related question seems to suggest this may not be possible:

[Magento - Checking if an Admin and a Customer are logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950077/magento-checking-if-an-admin-and-a-customer-are-logged-in)

Another related question, with a solution that didn't help my specific case:

[Magento : How to check if admin is logged in within a module controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342165/magento-how-to-check-if-admin-is-logged-in-within-a-module-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late Answer but if as I found it on google:

This it not possible.

Why? Because the default session name in the frontend is `frontend` and the session name in the backend is `admin`. Because of this, the session data of the admin is not available in the frontend.

Comment: I ended up encrypting a cookie and setting a session in database to handle it. You're correct, no luck doing it any 'official' way.

Comment: Yea, we thought about that way too, and ended up with a "IP developer feature", like in the magento config. I think, if we change the name of the session both to the same value, it should be no problem. But is this a security measure?

Comment: I wouldn't change the session to be the same, just because it sounds like you could get into unforeseen consequences. The encrypted cookie works great for me, and you don't have to mess with IPs. Implementation here: https://github.com/zschuessler/QuarkBar

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. What you need to do is switch the session data. You can do this with the following code:

```
  $switchSessionName = 'adminhtml';
  if (!empty($_COOKIE[$switchSessionName])) {
      $currentSessionId = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSessionId();
      $currentSessionName = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSessionName();
      if ($currentSessionId && $currentSessionName && isset($_COOKIE[$currentSessionName])) {
          $switchSessionId = $_COOKIE[$switchSessionName];
          $this->_switchSession($switchSessionName, $switchSessionId);
          $whateverData = Mage::getModel('mymodule/session')->getWhateverData();
          $this->_switchSession($currentSessionName, $currentSessionId);
      }
  }

  protected function _switchSession($namespace, $id = null) {
      session_write_close();
      $GLOBALS['_SESSION'] = null;
      $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
      if ($id) {
          $session->setSessionId($id);
      }
      $session->start($namespace);
  }
```

Comment: +1 for showing an alternative, even if it wouldn't be the best solution for my situation.

Comment: How would I get this to work if it was just on a CMS page template? Not sure what to do with your variables like $whateverData

Comment: This needs to be in PHP code. You can maybe reference to it with a depends from inside your template..

Comment: If you don't have the 'adminhtml' cookie, this code will create that cookie with same value as the frontend one, overwriting the frontend session. I think the if clause should also check if the adminhtml cookie exists as well, otherwise it's clear you are not logged in in the backend. Got this from this error in the system.log: Notice: Undefined index: adminhtml

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this :

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'))->isLoggedIn();
```

how about this ( I am not sure it will work or not )

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$apps = Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminSession->start();
if ($adminSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // check admin
}
```

Comment: This was a solution posted in one of my links. Works for the admin module, but not frontend, unfortunately.

Comment: No luck. Since we are working with the frontend session already, it might not be possible. Check the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950077/magento-checking-if-an-admin-and-a-customer-are-logged-in